# iron_worker: uninitialized constant error with active record class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, worker, ironworker

I am testing iron worker (used to be simple worker), which fails to recognize an active record class name in my Rails app on Heroku. You can find 'AdImpression' below, which is class name.

docs on Iron worker's support site says I can use active record objects freely but somehow that's not the case for me.

Any idea?

```
/mnt/sw_jobs/u17501/user_dir/daily_ad_campaign_counter_worker.rb:56:in `insert_data_on_specific_date': uninitialized constant DailyAdCampaignCounterWorker::AdImpression (NameError)
    from /mnt/sw_jobs/u17501/user_dir/daily_ad_campaign_counter_worker.rb:13:in `run'
    from /mnt/sw_jobs/u17501/user_dir/runner.rb:337:in `<main>'
job_data={"class_name"=>"DailyAdCampaignCounterWorker", "attr_encoded"=>"e30=\n", "file_name"=>"daily_ad_campaign_counter_worker.rb", "rails"=>{"env"=>"development", "version"=>"3.1.1"}, "sw_config"=>{"token"=>"Yd8Q6Nyobw2Ms7UQ93ZpNCcKUX4", "project_id"=>"4ef49d8acea6fe6ea30007ef", "database"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql2", "username"=>"XXXXXX", "port"=>3306, "host"=>"XXXXxx", "password"=>"aXXXXX", "database"=>"XXXXXX"}, "global_attributes"=>{}}}
I, [2011-12-27T10:36:30.980685 #11059]  INFO -- : IronWorker initialized.
Starting DailyAdCampaignCounterWorker 2011-12-27 10:36:30 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. It turns out that you have to merge models which are required to run the script because Iron worker changed their default settings.

Comment: Here's the docs on merging: https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_ruby/wiki/Merging